# What will happen to those who are mentally ill in the afterlife?

Tags: jannah, day-of-judgement, sick

As far as I know, mentally ill people will not be held accountable for anything they do simply because they do not have the mental capabilities to part right from wrong. Just like a child.

In that case, how will they be judged ? If they will go directly to the heaven, then isn't that unfair for rest of us ?

Note that I am not saying their lives are meaningless or anything. They can be a test for the society, parents etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> Narrated Ali ibn AbuTalib: The Prophet (ﷺ) said: There are three
>   (persons) whose actions are not recorded: a sleeper till he awakes, a
>   boy till he reaches puberty, and a lunatic till he comes to reason.
>   Abu Dawud said: Ibn Juraij has transmitted it from Al-Qasim b. Yazid
>   on the authority of 'Ali from the Prophet (ﷺ). This version adds: "and
>   an old man who is feeble-minded."([Abi Dawud](http://www.sunnah.com/abudawud/40/53))

and

> The Prophet(ﷺ) said:  “Four types of people will be tested on the day
>   of judgement: a deaf man who cannot hear anything, a mad man, an old
>   aged man and a man who died during fatrah (a period of time when no
>   messenger was sent to people). The deaf man will say: “Oh Allah, Islam
>   came while I cannot hear anything!”. The mad man will say: “Oh Allah,
>   Islam came while the boys throw animals’ excrement on me!”. The old
>   aged man will say: “Oh Allah, Islam came while I can understand
>   nothing”. And the man who died during a fatrah will say: “Oh Allah, I
>   witnessed no messenger from You”. Then Allah takes a promise from them
>   to obey Him. Then He will command them to enter hell, and who enters
>   it will find it peace and cool, and who disobeys will be dragged to
>   hell” (Masnad Ahmad)

**[Say], "Then is it other than Allah I should seek as judge while it is He who has revealed to you the Book explained in detail?" And those to whom We [previously] gave the Scripture know that it is sent down from your Lord in truth, so never be among the doubters.
And the word of your Lord has been fulfilled in truth and in justice. None can alter His words, and He is the Hearing, the Knowing.Quran(6-114,115)**

One of the beautiful name of Allah Swt is AL-HAKAM (The Judge,The giver of Justice)
Allah Swt judges among people with complete fairness ,Truth and with justice.It would not be our duty on Judgement day to judge people,He is Maliki youm Ad din (King of the Judgement day),We are Abd (Servant) of Allah Swt.So The Servant has to surrender or submit himself to Allah Swt.Prophet Muhammad ﷺ once said *“Who will be just if Allaah and His Messenger are not just?”*.

So Our limited knowledge and intelligence is not enough to understand the descisions taken by Allah Swt.Allah Swt is just and fair to all.

[image]

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: So, basically we don't know how will they be treated by Allah on the judgment day. Right ?

Comment: You answer is in the above mentioned Hadith.JazakAllah

Comment: It just says their actions are not recorded. Doesn't tell anything about their fate. Am I missing a point ?

Comment: Marwan ibn al-Hakam wrote to Muawiya ibn Abi Sufyan that a madman was brought to him who had killed a man. Muawiya wrote to him, "Tie him up and do not inflict any retaliation on him. There is no retaliation against a madman."(Muwatta) http://www.sunnah.com/urn/416290

Comment: Yes and of that it'll be logical to conclude they are not responsible for their actions. Still no clue about how will they ben judged. So, only Allah knows it about it then.

Comment: I have added the hadith and you would get your answer there In Sha Allah.

Comment: Sorry my friend, either it doesn't answers to my question or I fail to see it's point. Care to elaborate/explain the hadith for me ?

Comment: According to the hadith they would be tested on Judgement day ,so in this world it is not sure that Are they directly going to heaven or not.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, niyya(intension) is the key point to hold any person accountable. Since lunatics do not have the capacity to make any decision or pre-plan for any action, they are responsible for their actions. Allah knows the best and decides accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Salam and peace be upon our prophet.

In regards to your question, it is not "unfair" for the rest of us if people with a mental illness were not judged for wrongdoings they commit as a result of their illness. Our lives in comparison to theirs is a walk in the park. We have the mental capacity to distinguish right or wrong all the time while they don't (depending on the illness). A serious mental illness is one of the worst thing a person can endure in this life so no it's not unfair. Nor is their life meaningless. They are still people created by Allah just like you and I. Their life has meaning to themselves, Allah and people around them. Again, just like everyone else. I'm upset by the language in this thread and the way this topic is discussed. It proves yet again another obstacle we need to overcome as a Muslim brotherhood and that is accepting of those with mental illness. Not to call them "madmen" or "lunatics" but to acknowledge them as human beings and use appropriate language.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: That's really touching!